# Ruby simple regex syntax error

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm new to Ruby and i'm working on a code for a server.
The code is a half year old. In the meanwhile Chrome updated versions to version 14.

So here is my code:

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/[3-9]|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

As you can see Chrome 3-9 but now when i try to change it to:

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/[3-15]|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

I get a syntax error. Help me figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is here : `[3-15]` this is a character class with range of char from 3 to 1 that is not allowed.

I guees you want : `[3-9]|1[0-5]` that means 3 to 9 or 10 to 15

The complete regex is:

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/([3-9]|1[0-5])|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

Answer (score 3):

`[3-9]` is a [numeric range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html). It means a single digit between 3 or 9. Numeric ranges doesn't work in the way you expect: `[3-15]` is not a valid range.

If you simply want to match a digit range you can use `[0-9]{1,2}`. It matches everything between 0 and 99. Or `[0-9]+` to make it less restrictive.

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/[0-9]+|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

If you really want to validate the inclusion in the range 3-15, using regular expressions is not really the best choice. In fact, using regular expression your range should be `[3-9]|1[0-5]` and the more restrictive you want to be, the more complicated the regexp becomes.

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/(?:[3-9]|1[0-5])|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-   9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

Comment: Why isn't it the best choice?

Comment: I told you in the last sentence: the more sophisticated the match becomes, the more complex is your regexp. There is a point where you need to leave regexp and use code. For example, what would happen if you don't support Chrome 13? Validating a range 3-15 except 13 using a regexp forces you to write extremely complicated regexps.

Comment: Anyway, for now you can still use regexps but remember, when exceptions will arrive, don't try to solve everything in a regexp or simplify the problem. Do you really need to check the version number? Keep in mind that Chrome has a built-in update system, it's very unlikely that a user has a Chrome version < 3.

Answer (score 1):

[3-15] does not check the range. for range you have to use [3-9]|1[0-4] would match 1-14
e.g.

```
supported_browsers = /Chrome\/([3-9]|1[0-4])|Firefox\/[3-9]|\sMSIE\s|Konqueror\/[4-9]|Midori|Minefield|Shiretoko|IceCat|Opera\/9.|\sAppleWebKit/
```

Comment: `[1-9][0-4]` also matches `94`.